# dynamic data website using ado.net entity framework and mysql giving an error just on the server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-3.5, iis-7, dynamic-data

I have an asp.net dynamic data website .net 3.5 built on ado.net entity framework with mysql database.

Currently I have just one table in my entity model.

Everything is working fine on my local machine but when i uploaded on my server i got this error message:
"***More than one item in the metadata collection match the identity 'mtDBModelStoreContainer'***"

How can i solve this problem?

Note that this error happen when i open the table "WebsiteAdmin/users/List.aspx"

Comment: My wild guess is a bad connect string: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

- Are there any dll's on your machine that did not get deployed.
- Are there any duplicate lines in your configuration file (app/web.config)

Answer (score 0):

We have performed a test and succeeded in deploying Dynamic Data Entities Web Site using [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/).